# How can I make a bootable ISO from a bootable USB drive?

Tags: virtualbox, iso, bootable, chrome-os

I used a [set of instructions](https://github.com/imperador/chromefy) to create a bootable USB drive for ChromeOS. I want to install ChromeOS in VirtualBox. This is [apparently impossible](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=69605) to do from a USB drive. I tried mounting the 9GB .img file [as a floppy controller](https://superuser.com/questions/554862/how-to-convert-img-to-usable-virtualbox-format), but it [errors out](https://pastebin.com/raw/7WGmNDGn).

The only thing I can think to do, in order to get this installed in VirtualBox, is to write the .img to a USB, then try to copy the USB to an ISO and try to boot as a live ISO, as that is what would normally happen on a hardware install. (Reboot PC, boot from USB, ChromeOS boots, run a few commands and it's installed)

I'm making an attempt with ddrescue, but I don't imagine that'll work.

How can I make a bootable ISO to accomplish this task, or what other solution can you recommend to reach the end goal by any means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a bootable ISO image to USB and having it boot only works if the ISO image is specially prepared to be bootable in such a situation, using `isohybrid` or similar tool. That tool embeds another bootloader in the very beginning of the ISO image that is only used when the ISO image is written to USB.

The opposite, turning a bootable USB image to a bootable ISO would normally require installing a different, ISO9660-compatible bootloader.

However, you could fairly simply copy your `.img` into `.vdi`.

From your second link, [I found this procedure.](https://bethesignal.org/blog/2011/01/05/how-to-mount-virtualbox-vdi-image/)

A slight variation of it should be good for your purposes:

1.) First, create a `.vdi` file of the necessary size. The contents are unimportant, as they will be overwritten in the next step.

2.) Make it accessible as a block device:

```
modprobe nbd
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 <your vdi file>.vdi
```

3.) Now write your ChromeOS USB `.img` directly to the `.vdi` file:

```
dd if=/some/where/your-chromeos.img of=/dev/nbd0
```

This will automatically copy the partition table and all the partitions within the `.img` file to the `.vdi` file.

4.) Once done, disconnect the `.vdi` file from the device:

```
qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
```

Now you'll have a `.vdi` file you can use in lieu of an USB stick in the VirtualBox world. Configure it as an extra virtual disk for the new VM and boot from it.

Disclaimer: I don't have ChromeOS so I cannot test this procedure, but it should work in theory.